# Jmeter stops working in NON GUI mode

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to post messages from `JMETER` into to `Weblogic` in `non-gui` mode. As soon as I execute the command

```
./jmeter.sh -n -t testplan.jmx -l log.jtl
```

Jmeter is not responding and displays the following info

```
Creating summariser <summary>
Created the tree successfully using JMS Point-to-Point.jmx
Starting the test @ Mon Feb 13 09:51:22 GMT 2017 (1486979482989)
Waiting for possible shutdown message on port 4445.
```

Since I am trying to post messages to `weblogic`, I have also added `wlfulclient.jar` to `lib` dir of `JMETER`.

Both `jmeter` and `wls` are hosted on `Linux servers`
I have tried on 2.13 and 3.1 jmeter versions
Any hints on this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Jmeter is hanged, not even processed single message. Check jmeter log for error details .

Answer (score 0):

The message you display is a regular message and nothing indicates any issue occured.

Could you check the jmeter.log file for errors if any ? 
And then provide more details on your test plan .

Comment: Please find the log below:
2017/02/14 04:39:21 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error
2017/02/14 04:39:21 INFO  - jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group number 1 threads 1 ramp-up 1 perThread 1000.0 delayedStart=false
2017/02/14 04:39:21 INFO  - jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1
2017/02/14 04:39:21 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started
2017/02/14 04:39:21 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1

Comment: I don't see any error. If you can make it avilable in a more readable format it would be better.

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned, what are you seeing in the jmeter.log? If you suspect that it is *hanging* which I doubt in your case, please launch JMeter using the following options. Launch JVISUALVM and collect thread dumps. From the thread dumps, try to figure out what the threads are doing.

```
java -Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xms4g -Xmx4g -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=200 -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -Dgroovy.use.classvalue=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9010 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -jar "<Jmeter install directory>\bin\ApacheJMeter.jar"
```

Comment: I tried this but no luck, same behavior.
So as mentioned I am trying to post JMS messages from jmeter to weblogic, for that I have placed wlfulclient.jar also.
Is there anything else required here?

Comment: this will not resolve your issue. But it will help you to take thread dumps using JVisualVM. Run your Jmeter using the above and launch JVisualVM from the command prompt. Connect to your running JMeter JVM and take thread dumps and post the screenshot.